# Rep Digit Palindrome expressed as a Unique set of Pan Digital Relations

Tags: mathematics, no-computers

Allowed Operations:

Addition, Subtraction, Multiplication, Division, Exponentiation. Right and Left Bracket use permitted.

Express $2222$ in $2$ different ways using all the digits 1 to 9 only once in each expression.

$2222$  =

$2222$   =

Comment: So you can't use zero?

Comment: No..only 1 to 9,,all need to be used without repeating

Comment: And also, can you make, for example, 4 and 5, 45?

Comment: If you mean it as forty five..sure

Comment: For example: one of the terms could be..(5/1) ^ 3

Comment: You said no division, though...

Comment: Sorry..missed that..will edit now..thx for catching it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to try:

> $2222=1987+234-5+6$

and

> $2222=1986+234-5+7$

Answer (score 3):

Just a little bit after @JonMark Perry

> $(49+52) * (8+3) * (7-6+1)$

and technically different

> $(42+59) * (3+8) * (7-6+1)$

Comment: Good one.........

Comment: Just some prime factorization...

Answer (score 2):

Solution 1:

> To get a “big” number like $2222$, I decided to use powers.
>
>  $2^{11}=2048$ is close to $2222$ but is a bit too small.
>  I need to increase my solution by $2222-2048=174$.
>  I can express the power of $11$ as $3+8$ or $4+7$ or $5+6$.
>
>  Examining the $3+8$ case, the unused digits are: $1,4,5,6,7,9$.
>  We can easily make the number $174$ using the digits $1,7,4$.
>
>  To deal with the remaining digits $5,6,9$ we use two facts:
>  $1^n=1$ and multiplying by $1$ doesn’t change the value of an expression.
>
>  Finally, we get:
>
>  $2222=2^{3+8}+174 \times (6-5)^9$

Solution 2:

> Considering powers of $3$, I got a nicer solution:
>
>  $2222=3^7+1+2+4+5+6+8+9$